# How to pass filenames from "find" to "tr"?

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to learn how a couple of commands works and I want to make a simple script that will change uppercase letters in file names to lowercase.
I created that script:

```
find * -exec bash -c \
     'echo "${1##*/}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]";' _ {} \;
```

It works, but it only writes with echo lowercased file names, instead of changing them. On the other hand this piece of code:

```
 find * -exec bash -c \
     'tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]";' _ {} \;
```

acts as if I would only use:

```
tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

So, I want to learn and understand how to pass filenames that I can get from `find` and do anything with them using `tr`. Went already to manuals and google and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@tink points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034840/14122), if you want to rename the files, you need to actually invoke `mv`. `tr` just translates strings (and frankly, there's no good reason to use it for converting shell variables between upper and lower case if you're using bash 4.0 or later, which [has native case conversion available via parameter expansion syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification)).

The [Complex Actions section of UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions) shows a way to do this quite similar to the code you were already running:

```
find . -depth -exec bash -c '
  for old_name; do
    new_name=$(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<<"$old_name")
    [[ $old_name = "$new_name" ]] && continue
    mv -- "$old_name" "$new_name"
  done
' _ {} +;
```

...though personally, I would tend to avoid much of the complexity by performing the `mv` operations in the parent shell:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' old_name; do
  new_name=$(tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" <<<"$old_name") # or new_name=${old_name,,}
  [[ $old_name = "$new_name" ]] && continue
  mv -- "$old_name" "$new_name"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

---

Note that in the first case, we're using `find . -exec {} +`. Using `find .` is more reliable than `find *` since it doesn't rely on shell globbing; and `-exec ... _ {} +` is more efficient than `-exec ... _ {} \;` since it passes multiple names to one command, as opposed to starting a separate copy of bash for each name found.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... `tr` just does that; translates one character set to another, here upper to lower.  To actually **change** a filename you need to use `mv`.

Capture the names that actually would change, and then use `mv` on those; you can't just go `mv` for every file, because that would give you error messages of the type `mv: 'blah' and 'blah' are the same file` ...